# How To Resolve this trigger recursivity mind blow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

We got 3 tables : T1, T2, T3, which one got only one column (a int). And all are empty.
We have 6 triggers:

T1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER D1_1
BEFORE INSERT ON T1
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) < 1
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (6);


CREATE TRIGGER D1_2
AFTER INSERT ON T1
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) < 2
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (25);
```

T2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER D2_1
BEFORE INSERT ON T2
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3) < 1
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (15);


CREATE TRIGGER D2_2
AFTER INSERT ON T2
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) < 10
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (28);
```

T3:

```
CREATE TRIGGER D3_1
BEFORE INSERT ON T3
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) > 10
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (21);


CREATE TRIGGER D3_2
AFTER INSERT ON T3
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3) < 2
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (32);
```

Then we do :

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (0);
```

What append, in which order of insertion?

But i don't know the priority of linked BEFORE and AFTER insert.
For example, i think the begin of the procedure is :
BEFORE T1 -> insert T2 so -> BEFORE T2 -> insert T3 so -> beforer T3 (no match condition) so insert T2 ...?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The syntax you have shown is invalid for Postgres. Which DBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution order would be as follows:

```
insert into T1 values (0)
    trigger d1_1
    T2 has 0 records
    insert into T2 values (6)
        trigger d2_1
        T3 has 0 records
        insert into T3 values (15)
            trigger d3_1
            T2 has 0 records
            15 is now inserted into T3
            trigger d3_2
            T3 has 1 records
            insert into T2 values (32)
                trigger d2_1
                T3 has 1 records
                32 is now inserted into T2
                trigger d2_2
                T1 has 0 records
                insert into T1 values (28)
                    trigger d1_1
                    T2 has 1 records
                    28 is now inserted into T1
                    trigger d1_2
                    T2 has 1 records
                    insert into T3 values (25)
                        trigger d3_1
                        T2 has 1 records
                        25 is now inserted into T3
                        trigger d3_2
                        T3 has 2 records
        6 is now inserted into T2
        trigger d2_2
        T1 has 1 records
        insert into T1 values (28)
            trigger d1_1
            T2 has 2 records
            28 is now inserted into T1
            trigger d1_2
            T2 has 2 records
    0 is now inserted into T1
    trigger d1_2
    T2 has 2 records
Done.
```

At the end:

- T1 has 28, 28, 0
- T2 has 32, 6
- T3 has 15, 25

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day